# Firebase query data shows on another table in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 tables, 1 table for pending data and another table for approved data. My problem is my query on showing the pending data on pending table also appears in my approved table. Here's the picture

[image: data table picture]

Here's the code for the pending query,

```
var database =   firebase.database().ref().child('Request').child('Pending');
database.once('value', function(snapshot){
snapshot.forEach(function(data){
           var userEmail = data.val().username;
   var ReqStatus = data.val().request_status;
    var userId = snapshot.keys;

  content +='<tr>'
  content +='<td>' + userEmail+ '</td';
  content +='<tr><td>' + ReqStatus+ '</td>'; 
  content +='<td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><button id="btnApprove" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Approve" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#approve" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p></td>';

content +='<td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" id="btnDelete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></td>';
  content +='</tr></tr>';
});
$('#mytable').append(content);

});
```

Here's the code for approved table,

```
var databasez = firebase.database().ref().child('Request').child('Approved');
databasez.once('value', function(snapshot){
snapshot.forEach(function(data){
           var userEmail = data.val().username;
   var ReqStatus = data.val().request_status;
    var userId = snapshot.keys;

  content +='<tr>'
  content +='<td>' + userEmail+ '</td';
  content +='<tr><td>' + ReqStatus+ '</td>'; 
  content +='</tr></tr>';
});
$('#tableApproved').append(content);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you don't re-initialize the `content` variable.

Do as follows:

```
var databasez = firebase.database().ref().child('Request').child('Approved');
databasez.once('value', function(snapshot){
  var content = '';    // <-- Re-initialize here
  snapshot.forEach(function(data){
           var userEmail = data.val().username;
     var ReqStatus = data.val().request_status;
      var userId = snapshot.keys;

    content +='<tr>'
    content +='<td>' + userEmail+ '</td';
    content +='<tr><td>' + ReqStatus+ '</td>'; 
    content +='</tr></tr>';
  });
  $('#tableApproved').append(content);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice that one. Thank you very much sir!